# Change vb.net Resource

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am working with a vb.net program that has a microsoft word help document associated with it. I have replaced the document with an updated help ducument but the document will not change. When I click on the help button that is supposed to call the document it opens the old document even though I replaced the old file in the resource file with the new one. What would be the cause for this?

Additional Note: When I publish the application to the server the old help manuel shows but if I just publish it to the computer I am working on and launch it the new help manuel shows.

If any more information is needed just let me know.

PRBL_121220_SWL_Tracker is the name of the help file.

```
Imports Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word
'create temporary folders and files to simulate the environment needed to create report
Module Help
    Sub Build_Help()
        Dim wordApp As New Word.Application
        Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
        Dim helpFile As String
        Dim exlFile As String
        Dim helpFolder As String
        helpFolder = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath
        helpFolder = helpFolder & "swltemp"
        My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(helpFolder & "\F025-14-03-410_PVLc")
        helpFile = helpFolder & "\130820.help.doc"
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(helpFile, My.Resources.PRBL_121220_SWL_Tracker)
        wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(helpFile)
        wordApp.Visible = 1


        exlFile = helpFolder & "\F025-14-03-410_PVLc\LIST_130709_F25_PVLc_SAP_BOMs.xlsx"
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(exlFile, My.Resources.LIST_130709_F25_PVLc_SAP_BOMs)
        exlFile = helpFolder & "\F025-14-03-410_PVLc\REP_20130611_Matrix_F025-14-03-xxx_.xlsx"
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(exlFile, My.Resources.LIST_130709_F25_PVLc_SAP_BOMs)
        exlFile = helpFolder & "\F025-14-03-410_PVLc\SAb_F025-14-03-410_4_k.xls"
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(exlFile, My.Resources.SAb_F025_14_03_410_4_k)


        exlFile = helpFolder & "\REP_130709_F25_PVLc_SAP_B_SWLTest.xlsm"
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(exlFile, My.Resources.REP_130712_F25_PVLc_SAP_B_SWLTest)
        wordDoc.Hyperlinks(1).Address = helpFolder & "\F025-14-03-410_PVLc"
        wordDoc.Hyperlinks(2).Address = exlFile
        wordDoc.Save()
        wordDoc = Nothing
        wordApp = Nothing
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: In order for us to help you, you'll need to give us more specifics.  Showing us the code that actually loads the document would be very helpful.

Comment: I will try to do that but it will take a bit.

Comment: That's much better, thanks.  So, you're writing the resource to a temp file and then opening it with the `Word.Application` object...  And it's presumably not throwing an exception, right?  I don't see why that wouldn't work, except that the assembly is out of date on the other machine and you just don't realize it.  Perhaps an older version of the assembly from a different folder than you expect is being used?  Have you checked to make sure that there isn't an old copy of the word document stuck in that temp folder?

Comment: There are no exceptions thrown by the program and everything work fine it just won't update the help file. I am not sure what you mean by " except that the assembly is out of date on the other machine and you just don't realize it". Sorry I am a bit new to vb.net and I did not write this program but instead inherited it.

Comment: The resource is embedded as part of the assembly (i.e. the exe or dll file).  So, if it write out the new document on your machine, but it writes out an older version of the document on another machine, the most obvious first thing to check would be to make sure that that other machine--the one having the problem--is indeed running the new version of the assembly.

Comment: I do not know how to view the folder assicated with the program on the server. If I look into the resource folder there is just a "consolidate.ico.deploy" folder. If I try to open it the text is jsut nonsense.

Comment: At run-time, there is no folder and there is no resource file.  When you build (i.e. compile) the application, the compiler embeds the resources in the assembly (as part of the exe or dll file).  Therefore, if the resource is out of date, that probably means the whole exe or dll is out of date.

Comment: Alright I don't understand how this works then. I just want to make sure we are on the same page though.The file is not run from the server but is downloaded then installed to the client pc, so it should create its own new temporary folder with the new application files right?

Comment: I don't know.  There are many ways to distribute an application.  I don't know what method of distribution you are using, so I can't answer that for you.  If that's how you are doing it, I can only take your word for it.  All I'm saying is that's the first thing I'd check--to make sure that the version of the assembly that is being run is the same on both machines.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2010 and There is a text field for publishing the folder and I put in the location. It is made to be available offline as well.